# jitterbit-password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: windows, postgresql, pgadmin, jitterbit

Hello I am using Jitterbit integration service to integrate PostgreSQL with salesforce. I have Jitterbit Studio & jitterbit agent installed on my windows 7 machine.

[Click this link to see screenshot of the error message in my jitterbit Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMFev.png)

I was trying to add a PostgreSQL source in Jitterbit studio, But I got an error :

```
Failed to connect to database. FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" (SqlState: 28P01).

Studio version: 8.24.2.2
Studio platform: Windows 7 - Java 1.8.0_121
Cloud: https://emea-west.jitterbit.com
User:myemail@gmail.com
Org: Demo [ID = 214458]
Environment: Default Environment [ID = 227118]
Agent Group: Jitterbit Cloud Agent Group [ID = 1542] [Lowest Agent Version = 8.24.1.1]
Project: New Project [GUID = dff2e842-3752-4f19-99cf-3a96c675c18a]
Timestamp: 2017-06-30 14:11:08.121
```

The username and password of PostgreSQL is "postgres" & "root" respectively.But still it is giving me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file  **pg_hba.conf.sample** which is located in your PostgreSQL folder.

Add a below line to the existing content of file :

```
host all all trust
```

Comment: I have updated the pg_hba.conf file but it still gives me below error
"FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres" "